# jquery jsonp and understanding how the call back works

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

So I wrote an ajax call to github using dataType: json, which worked on my local machine, but it appears that I need to use dataType: jsonP to deal with the cross domain issues. So can anyone help me make the necessary changes. (BTW github appears to support jsonp dataTypes - https://github.com/pgxn/pgxn-api/wiki/JSONP)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/jeffreycwitt/prollecture1/tags",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(returndata) {
        if (returndata.length === 0) {
            $("#versionBox").remove();
        }
        else if (returndata.length === 1) {
            $("#versionBox").remove();
        }
        else {
            $.each(returndata, function() {
                $("#versionBox").show();
                var tag = this["name"];
                console.log(tag);
                var currentVersion = $("#editionNumber").text();
                if (tag.substring(1) === currentVersion) {
                    tag = tag + " (Current Version)";
                }
                var linkname = "textdisplay.php?flag=<?php echo $fs; ?>&ed=" + tag;
                $('#versionSubBox').append("<p><a href='" + linkname + "'>View Version: " + tag + "</a></p>");
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Like i said, this was working when I was just using dataType, json, but its not working with jsonP. I'm under the impressions github will send back the regular json wrapped in something named by the callback parameter added to the call `?callback=?`. (This parameter is added automatically by jquery when the dataType is changed to jsonp. **So do I need to somehow modify my success function to parse through the wrapper?**

Comment: Is it intentional that your url comes back empty ( [ ] )?

Comment: now try it -- also if use curl and add ?callback=foo -- you'll see what the return data will look like. I guess I just don't know how to parse what returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpFE6/1/).

The problem you are having is that you are trying to access a `.length` property on the 
`returndata` object and such property doesn't exist:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "tarball_url": "https://github.com/jeffreycwitt/prollecture1/tarball/v0.2",
            "commit": {
                "sha": "46a8aea57cd095a603f194f83cd4a18adcb35908",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jeffreycwitt/prollecture1/commits/46a8aea57cd095a603f194f83cd4a18adcb35908"
            },
            "name": "v0.2",
            "zipball_url": "https://github.com/jeffreycwitt/prollecture1/zipball/v0.2"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "status": 200,
        "X-RateLimit-Limit": "5000",
        "X-RateLimit-Remaining": "4993"
    }
}
```

I guess you meant `returndata.data.length` because you have a `data` property which is an array.

So:

```
var data = returndata.data;
if (data.length === 0) {
    $("#versionBox").remove();
}
else if (data.length === 1) {
    $("#versionBox").remove();
}
else {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $("#versionBox").show();
        var tag = this["name"];
        console.log(tag);
        var currentVersion = $("#editionNumber").text();
        if (tag.substring(1) === currentVersion) {
            tag = tag + " (Current Version)";
        }
        var linkname = "textdisplay.php?flag=<?php echo $fs; ?>&ed=" + tag;
        $('#versionSubBox').append("<p><a href='" + linkname + "'>View Version: " + tag + "</a></p>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Github is weird. They actually change the response when called via JSONP.

Comment: @Anurag, yeah, that's the problem that the OP is having. If he had used FireBug or a javascript debugging tool he would have seen this immediately. Since Phil Haack joined them, strange things started to happen :-)

Comment: Success -- thanks very much -- basically the jsonp adds another layer that I needed to parse through -- so once i used returndata.data[0].length -- everything worked out just fine

Answer (score 0):

The answer (specific to GitHub, I guess) lies in finding one's way through the extra layer of data that is not included in the normal json call.

So here how the code has changed. At three specific points I changed `returndata` to `returndata.data`.

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/jeffreycwitt/prollecture1/tags",
dataType: "jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
success: function(returndata) {
    if (returndata.data[0].length === 0) {
        $("#versionBox").remove();
    }
    else if (returndata.data[0].length === 1) {
        $("#versionBox").remove();
    }
    else {
        $.each(returndata.data, function() {
            $("#versionBox").show();
            var tag = this.name;
            console.log(tag);
            var currentVersion = $("#editionNumber").text();
            if (tag.substring(1) === currentVersion) {
                tag = tag + " (Current Version)";
            }
            var linkname = "textdisplay.php?flag=<?php echo $fs; ?>&ed=" + tag;
            $('#versionSubBox').append("<p><a href='" + linkname + "'>View Version: " + tag + "</a></p>");
        });

    }
 }
});
```